# Nonparametric test for largely skewed count data

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, count-data

My research design looks as follows: an experimental game with 4 participants (human subjects), repeated for 20 rounds. During each round, participants are allowed to form bilateral coalitions which are “frozen” until the end of a round. Hence, six different possible coalitions exist, but maximum two coalitions can emerge during a single round. The same setup is tested through a simulation, where simulation agents follow pre-set decision rules to form coalitions, the difference from the experiment being that all simulation rounds are independent.

For the experiment and for the simulation, I have the data on the number of times each particular coalition was formed. It can be visually represented on a bar chart, on which each colored bar corresponds to each of the possible coalitions, and the vertical axis shows the number of times it occurred (count variables).

[image]

My general idea is to understand whether stable coalition relationships emerge between participants in the experiment as they play repeatedly: for example, whether participant 1 tends to form coalitions with participant 2 more often than with other players.

To that end, I would like to test:

1. Whether there are statistical differences between the frequency of
   occurrences of different coalitions;
2. Whether the experimentally observed frequency distribution
   statistically differs from a theoretical benchmark (each coalition
   occurs with the equal 1/6=0.15 probability).

What would be the appropriate test in this case given that I am working count data which is (a) not normally distributed, (b) is largely skewed (a numeric outcome is frequently zero)?